# Delete TFS Collection after failure

Tags: sql-server-2008, team-foundation-server

I created a new TFS Collection and it failed at the end or something didn't go right. I have a new database representing the collection, but when I try to attach it or even list it, TFS can't find the collection.

Is this a bug? Did TFS try and make a database before it knew if it would fail or not?

How do I clean up the DB or delete the now invisible collection?

Answer (score 0):

Is the collection showing in the TFS console? If not I think you can just remove the database.

If the collection is showing, and can be removed then do do, otherwise you have a problem. When it happened to me<sup>1</sup> I restored the TFS system from backup.

---

<sup>1</sup> This happened to me when importing a TFS2008 system into a TFS 2010 Project Collection and it failed late in the conversion process.

Comment: Can I just drop the collection DB from sql server? Or is there a bunch of extra stuff floating around now?

Comment: @firebellys: The collection could be listed in the main configuration database (and thus the TFS instance knows about it): those records would not be removed by dropping the collection db.